# magento.cron.log issue M2.4.6

Tags: cron, magento2.4

I have migrated a dev website to latest M2.4.6.

I had an issue with cron jobs set on PHP 7.4 and get this message in magento.cron.log:
Magento supports PHP 8.1.0 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

So I did:
`bin/magento cron:remove (to remove past cron based on PHP 7.4)`
`bin/magento cron:install (to reinstall it with running PHP 8.1.0`

Result with crontab -l:
#~ MAGENTO START bc81a5a70829ed737e67bb2014942076082ae2f1543de68809b0d1c8d782c20f

- - - - - /usr/bin/php8.1 /.../.../www/.../bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/.../www/.../var/log/magento.cron.log

#~ MAGENTO END bc81a5a70829ed737e67bb2014942076082ae2f1543de68809b0d1c8d782c20f`

I know and see that cron jobs are now working (warmer module now automatically warm pages while it was stopped before, etc.)

However, my file magento.cron.log doesn't log the cron jobs and is not updated at all.
( I can still see error message Magento supports PHP 8.1.0 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html and no new lines are created).

Does someone have an idea to solve it ?

Many thanks